# Regex pattern to get the string using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, pattern-matching

There is a string like this:

```
Booking cost: <strong><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>165.00</span></strong>
```

I would like to get the 165.00 , which is inside the 165.00 pattern.

After some studies I found the pattern can build like this:

```
var regex = new RegExp("</span>", "g");
var input = "Booking cost: <strong><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>165.00</span></strong>";
var output = input.replace(regex, "test");
```

However, the code is to replace the text inside instead of obtain the text, how to get the text inside the pattern?

Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Without Regex we can just split the string and get the value.

```js
var input = 'Booking cost: <strong><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&#36;</span>165.00</span></strong>';

var output = input.split("</span>")[1];
console.log(output)
```